# How do I correctly pass a block handler into this function in Swift?

Tags: ios, closures, objective-c-blocks, swift

After reading about Swift Closures and trying to use the same syntax to pass a anonymous function into the handler I cannot get it to compile. How can I correctly re-create the following functioning objective c code in Swift?

Here is the objective c code that I am trying to re-create in swift

```
 [self.motionManager
     startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
     withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *data, NSError *error)
     {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        ^{

                            float xx = data.acceleration.x;
                            float yy = -data.acceleration.y;
                            float angle = atan2(yy, xx);

                            self.dropitBehavior.gravity.angle = angle;
                         });
     }
 ];
```

Here are few failed attempts at re-creating the code in swift:

```
self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue(), withHandler: {
            (data: CMAccelerometerData(), error: NSError()) -> Void = {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    var xx = data.acceleration.x
                    var yy = -data.acceleration.y
                    var angle = atan2(yy, xx)

                    self.dropitBehavior.gravity.angle = angle
                }
            }
  })

self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue(), withHandler: {
            (data: CMAccelerometerData(), error: NSError()) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    var xx = data.acceleration.x
                    var yy = -data.acceleration.y
                    var angle = atan2(yy, xx)

                    self.dropitBehavior.gravity.angle = angle
                }
            }
 })
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By doing `CMAccelerometerData()` and `NSError()` you are actually calling the initializers of those classes. You just need to use their types. However, because in objective-C, pointers can be nil, when you translate the types to Swift, you need to use optionals. The convention is to use [Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_436). Also, you separate the parameters of an anonymous closure with `in` not additional curly brackets:

```
self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue(), withHandler: {
    (data: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in
    // internal implementation
})
```

Also, because the types can be inferred from the parameter type, you don't have to even specify the types for the parameters:

```
self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue(), withHandler: {
    (data, error) in
    // internal implementation
})
```

Also, if a block is the last parameter to a method / function call, you can define it outside of the parenthesis:

```
self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue()) {
    (data, error) in
    // internal implementation
}
```

This way you don't need the closing `)` after the closure.

That creates the final version with your internal implementation:

```
self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue()) {
    (data, error) in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        var xx = data.acceleration.x
        var yy = -data.acceleration.y
        var angle = atan2(yy, xx)

        self.dropitBehavior.gravity.angle = angle
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I am getting an error 'Missing argument for parameter #2 in call' which highlights the dispatch_async line

Comment: @nearpoint Sorry, I was missing the opening curly bracket of the async block. I updated my answer

Comment: Ah thanks so much this answer is extremely helpful. I will reference it many times

Comment: ah and knowing about the third point (if the closure if the last argument you can put it outside the parentheses) makes me understand better why dispatch_async syntax is the way it is

Comment: @nearpoint Yup, the syntax can look somewhat strange with that until you get used to it

Comment: @drewag isn't there must be NSOperationQueue.mainQueue() or currentQueue()? Have strange error also, my handler doesn't called :/ I tried yours and have no effect too. Do you know why this could occur?

Comment: came here to upvote this. The 3rd syntax had bugged me for some point. Coming from python/node, 3rd syntax didnt make sense. i guess syntactic sugar!